# Select max date from joined tables with columns that has unique values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to get the most recent date from joined tables with unique values in 2 columns. How do I do this? I have also tried the ranking (but John has the same rank) and tried rownum = 1, but I still get the same results below for some reason

```
Name    ID    Email         DeptNo DeptScore   OnDate
John   A46 john@doe.com       100    50         5/11/2011
John   A46 johndoe@aol.com    200    75         7/21/2015
Alice  B33 alice@hotmail.com  100    50         4/15/2014
```

I want to get the following:

```
Name    ID    Email         DeptNo DeptScore   OnDate
John  A46  johndoe@aol.com    200    75        7/21/2015
Alice B33  alice@hotmail.com  100    50        4/15/2014
```

My query

```
select distinct e.name, e.id, e.email, d.deptno, d.deptscore, d.ondate
from
  emp e
inner join dept d on
      d.deptno = e.dnum 
  and d.ondate = e.livedate
  and d.ondate = (select max(m.ondate)
                  from dept m
                  where d.ondate = m.ondate)
--where e.id in ('A46','B33')
```

Comment: I think one of the two tables you mentioned is missing. Please add it (and also indicate who-is-who in the tables and your query).

Comment: Try my updated answer exactly it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the below Query, it will solve your problem.

```
select  name,
        id,
        email,
        deptno,
        deptscore,
        ondate
from  (select   e.name,
                e.id,
                e.email,
                d.deptno, 
                d.deptscore, 
                d.ondate,
                rank() over(partition by e.id,e.name order by d.ondate desc) rn
        from emp e join
             dept d
             on d.deptno = e.dnum and d.ondate = e.livedate
      ) s
where rn = 1;
```

Output:

```
NAME    ID  EMAIL                DEPTNO DEPTSCORE   ONDATE
John    A46 johndoe@aol.com      200    75          21-JUL-15
Alice   B33 alice@hotmail.com    100    50          15-APR-14
```

Comment: . . Couldn't you format the query better?  I want to upvote this because it is technically correct, but the query is not neatly formatted.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I have updated my answer with the good formatting of SQL, you can vote up plz.